# Symfony 3 - isGranted doesn't work for roles

Tags: php, symfony, roles

I have a UserCas entity that has a database role array (the same principle used for FOSUserBundle).

By going through the security.yml, I manage to restrict the access to my pages according to the roles, but when I use the is_granted, it does not take into account my roles, I do not understand why ...

I have :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/accueil, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
   # - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }
    - { path: ^/admin/*, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

[image]

My UserCas entity :

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity;

use Serializable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Site\PagesBundle\Security\Traits\traitUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\PaquetDDLCas;

/**
 * UserCas
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_cas")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\PagesBundle\Repository\UserCasRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("mail")
 */
class UserCas implements \Serializable, UserInterface
{

    use traitUser;


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;



    /************ MODIF ****************/

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    protected $roles = [];

     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addRole($role)
    {
        $role = strtoupper($role);
        if ($role === ['ROLE_USER']) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
            $this->roles[] = $role;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array_unique(array_merge(['ROLE_USER'], $this->roles));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->getRoles(), true);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function removeRole($role)
    {
        if (false !== $key = array_search(strtoupper($role), $this->roles, true)) {
            unset($this->roles[$key]);
            $this->roles = array_values($this->roles);
        }

        return $this;
    }

        /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $this->roles = array();

        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $this->addRole($role);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function resetRoles()
    {
        $this->roles = [];
    }

    /******************* FIN MODIF  *********************/



    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setEnabled(true);
        $this->roles = array();

    }



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }



    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }



    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->mail
        ]);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->mail
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }



    /*********************** Méthodes pour UserInterface ***************************/

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {

    }


}
```

If my twig file, I want to display something just if I have the ROLE_ADMIN :

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}

//...

{% endif %}
```

But it doesn't work.

And in my controler, if I make a conditon like :

```
if (is granted('ROLE_ADMIN))
{
   dump('yes');
}

else
{
  dump('no');
}
```

I've the dump('no').

But With the access control in the security.yml, restricted access works

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Your addRole is messed up since you are comparing $role with an array.  But I don't think that is causing the problem.  IsGranted actually uses the token roles (not the user roles) to check permissions.  Normally they should match but you might want to check to be sure.

Comment: Please note that your PHP code will never get through the "compilation" fase of PHP.

Comment: Nothing big, but you should use `json` type and not `array` type for roles. Your `addRole` is indeed messed up, and if the form have a select (with multiple=true) or checkbox to handle roles, `addRoles` isn't required at all. in PHP, you wrote `if(is granted('ROLE_ADMIN')` but it should be `if($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))`. In twig, you should do `{{ dump(is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') }}`. Update your question according to what you get with that.

Comment: I would assume, that the the `^/admin/*` entry in your access_control is completely ignored, since the `^/` entry before already matches all requests, but hell, I might be wrong ...

Comment: @Jakumi didn't notice, but you're right. The last route is ignored.

Comment: Hello, and sorry for waiting, I was at rest. Thank you for your answers, they helped me solve the problem. However, I did not have to change the type to json. Is it really necessary? On the other hand, is it possible to update the token automatically when a change is made? Because when I change the role from my created interface, I have to reconnect for the changes to take effect.